# cloud mine xcode

Tags: ios

I'm getting this error: `::[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'`

I checked my object is initialized properly but still getting this error. Using CloudMine.

```
(void)addInventory:(Inventory *)inventory {

    [_inventoryList addObject:inventory];

    [inventory save:^(CMObjectUploadResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"status: %@", [response.uploadStatuses objectForKey:inventory.objectId]);

        if (![[response.uploadStatuses objectForKey:inventory.objectId] isEqualToString:@"created"]) {
            // Alert the user
            NSString *message = @"The item could not be created.";
            if (response.error)
                message = [response.error localizedDescription];
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[response.error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];
        }

    }];
```

Comment: None of the code you posted makes a call to the setObject:forKey: method of an NSMutableDictionary. Look at the stack track in the debugger to see which line of code is making this call. The error is telling you that you are trying to add an object to a dictionary but the key is nil.

Comment: Is this still an issue? What version of the CloudMine library are you using? Can you give us the entire stack trace? If this is not an issue, you can write your answer below and answer it yourself, so others can know how you solved this particular issue.